# Python Multiprocessing function stuck inside one function with while loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to run two programs simultaneously. I have got it working using threading. Now I am trying to do the same using multiprocessing. But when while loop is used in program run via multiprocessing, only one function keeps on executing and second function is not executed. How to transfer the control to second function. Code tried has been shown:

```
from multiprocessing import Proces

def func1():

    while True:
         print ('Working1')

def func2():

    while True:
         print ('Working2')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Process(target = func1).start()
    Process(target = func2).start()
```

Comment: Code works on my machine.

Comment: I am running it on Python3 IDLE. It keeps on printing 'Working1' and func2 is not executed. I want 'Working1' and 'Working2' to be printed at same time. Please check again whether both functions are executed simultaneously or not.

Comment: Run from the command line to exclude any IDE interference. Also state your OS.

Comment: Running it from command line produces same result. Only Working1 keeps on printing as output.  Using OS Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 Stretch .

Comment: It's odd. Can you run your code on another OS and see if the problem is there as well?

Comment: from multiprocessing import `Process`. Fix the typo and the code should run.